Equal height columns using Swiper in free mode
I am trying to create flexbox equal height columns using Swiper in freemode.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-freemode-forked-t59k2l?workspaceId=eee5ba17-3be5-442c-9d85-157396198d4f
It works by adding display: flex to the .swiper-wrapper slot using the Inspector in the shadow DOM because this is the parent of the <swiper-slide>.
How can I set the CSS of the parent of  to be flex?

The link is broken. Please make sure to include a [mre] in the question itself.

Fixed the link to public access

Please also add the code example to the question.

Details should not be on an external site - all relevant content needs to be here, in your question, along with data/behavior/error details (a [mcve], as pointed out already)

By default, swiper-slide has height: 100%.
Set swiper-slide { height: auto; }
